# jquery.form terminating; zero elements found by selector error in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image-uploading

Hello I am using this [jquery plugin](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html) to upload image with ajax

This is my html code

```
 <form name="image_form" id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>

   <input type="file" name="image" id="image" tabindex="2" value="<?=$_POST['image']?>" />
</form>
  <div id='preview'>
  </div>
```

This is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
$('#image').live('change', function()   
{ 
$("#preview").html('');
//$("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
$("#imageform").ajaxForm(
{
target: '#preview'
}).submit();
});
});
```

and this is **ajaximage.php** code

```
<?php
//include('db.php');

echo "AAAA";
session_start();
$session_id='1'; // User session id
$path = "images/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
echo "bb".$name;
if(strlen($name))
{
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
if($size<(1024*1024)) // Image size max 1 MB
{
$actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{
    echo "ccc";
//mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
echo "<img src='images/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview'>";
}
else
echo "failed";
}
else
echo "Image file size max 1 MB"; 
}
else
echo "Invalid file format.."; 
}
else
echo "Please select image..!";
exit;
}
?>
```

I got the reason why it's happening but how to resolve it I don't know ? The reason is that I have two forms

```
<form name="main_form" id="form" action="<?=$action?>" name="pkgfrm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

under this I have many fields like First name , Age etc.  and the **other one form** also comese under this form

```
<form name="image_form" id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
```

Becuase of two form tag that plugin is not working . But I need both forms how can I do this. Help me Please

Answer (score -1):

It should not be a Problem Unless you use nested form .

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more in detail?

Comment: if you are trying to use nested forms try iframe